# Facebook - how to get

Tags: ios, facebook, ios5, ios6, sharekit

I am looking to implement the ShareSdk for an iOS app. And it needs these parameters:

```
#define SHKFacebookUseSessionProxy  NO 
#define SHKFacebookKey              @""
#define SHKFacebookSecret           @""
#define SHKFacebookSessionProxyURL  @""
```

And provides this url where to get it:
http://www.facebook.com/developers

But I am not finding how to get those parameters there. Would anyone be able to explain the steps to get those parameters?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to [Facebook Apps Page](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/), create a new app, get your keys.

Comment: thank you. That seems to be the right url. The one provided by sharekit seems to not have been right.